# Python 2.7.2 if/or unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, logic

I am learning Python at the moment and I have hit an issue.
Observe this code:

```
while 1:
    print "How many lines do you want to add to this file?"

    number_of_lines = raw_input(">").strip()

    if not(number_of_lines.isdigit()) or number_of_lines > 10:
        print "Please try a number between 1 and 10 inclusive."
        continue
```

The code asks a user for a number, and checks it's validity. However for some reason, the code always displays the error, even if the user does enter a valid number less than 10.

I have probably made a small error somewhere but I can't figure it out... being a python novice!

Hope you can help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI in general you should use `try...except`: the slogan is EAFP not LBYL.

Comment: @katrielalex Thanks, I will consider this in future but I'm not that far into it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When returned from `raw_input`, your `number_of_lines` variable is a *string*. You need to convert it to an integer before comparing with 10:

```
not(number_of_lines.isdigit()) or int(number_of_lines) > 10
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd try to convert the string into an integer first, catch the error if they put in something else.  This also let's you drop the `isdigit` call.  Like so:

```
while 1:
    print "How many lines do you want to add to this file?"

    try:
        number_of_lines = int(raw_input(">").strip())
    except ValueError:
        print "Please input a valid number."
        continue

    if number_of_lines > 10:
        print "Please try a number between 1 and 10 inclusive."
        continue
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will consider this next time but I wanted to avoid using try/except because I'm still a novice and haven't got that far yet! I have upvoted your answer though.